# How to find out the server side framework using Axis2?

Tags: web-services, apache-axis

After going through the following article I came to know that if Axis2 is used on both ends, we could expect high improvements in performance.

Link : http://wso2.org/library/91

```
      I'm writing code to consume a webservice. I'm just curious to know the framework used on the server side. How do I do it programatically using Axis2.
```

Answer (score 1):

Server side you can use any java class.The following are the server side styles that axis provides.
Service Styles - RPC, Document, Wrapped, and Message

Also see the [documentation here](http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html#ServiceStylesRPCDocumentWrappedAndMessage).

Answer (score 0):

There is no such API available as such. Of course, such API is not supposed to be there at all. The whole point of using web services is interoperability i.e. the server doesn't care how the client is implemented and the client does not care how the server is implemented. Defining such an API does not make any sense, adds no business value except curiosity as in your case above.

Albeit, It still might be possible to do so, unofficially. Try to send some parameter value which is not correct business value. From the fault that is generated, it might also give stacktrace of the server through which you can probably guess the server side framework being used.